# JQuery - Remove part of string and keep the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, dynamic-variables

I'm receiving multiple strings from a API and sometimes I have a string that looks like this.

```
first part <!-- Slut på Mall: variable --> second part
```

I want to use jQuery to exclude the part before and the "*Slut... **variable** -->*". Leaving me with the second part.

Just to be clear, the variable is dynamic and will change.

I have been playing around with **replace**, and **match** but so far I have failed. I have understood that regex is the way to go

```
regex = /Mall:.*\s+-->(.*)\z/
```

But I don't know what function to use with that?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville i know, i was referring to "Slut på Mall" :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var secondPart = "<!--" + yourApiString.split("<!--")[1];
```

Will return  `<!-- Slut på Mall: variable --> second part`

Comment: @Jack: happened to know the syntax off the top of my head. I love doing string manipulations without RegEx, it makes me feel so clever. ^.^

Comment: @Philip: No problem. Would you be kind enough to accept and possibly upvote my answer if it was helpful? :)

Comment: @Jack Thanks even though Elliot beat you to it!

Comment: @ElliotBonneville yes in 6 minutes ;)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville 

I acctually changed it to test = secondPage.split("-->")[1];

Comment: @Philip: Ah, okay, cool. I may have misunderstood the output string you were looking for, but I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to still use a regex and replace, [this is how](http://jsfiddle.net/9GYdn/4/) you *could* go about it.

```
var x = "first part <!-- Slut på Mall: variable --> second part";
var y = x.replace(/.*<!--/, "<!--");
```

This replaces everything before `<!--` including those four characters but ends up placing them back in.

If you just wanted "second part", then you could just do the following:

```
var y = x.replace(/.*-->/, "");
```

Thereby removing every character leading up to `-->` and itself.